# Transfering between terminals at Tokyo Narita as an arriving international passenger

Tags: transit, japan, nrt

We arrive in Narita Airport at Terminal 1. We haven't arranged any SIM card for our iPhones and would like to get hold of one at the airport. I've seen people recommending BIC camera stores for relatively cheap SIM cards, and I see that there is a BIC store in Narita Terminal 2. (I also see that there will be one in Terminal 1 opening June 1, but that doesn't help with my trip.)

Would we transfer between the terminals before or after passing through immigration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## You have a preference on the SIM

If you research on the Internet and have decided the brand, features (e.g. Unlimited data usage, throttled speed vs. limited data usage, unthrottled speed) and the budget, you can head straight to the listed retailer after arrival.

Related: [How can I find the cheapest prepaid SIM card for a given country?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/102032/)

### Changing terminal for Bic Camera (or any specific retailer)

Take the [free shuttle bus](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/access/shuttlebus/) after you have cleared the customs and immigration.

### Alternative: buying in flight

Some airlines might sell SIM cards in their flight. If it fits your requirement, you might just buy from them.

## You don't have a preference, any SIM and retailer is fine

There are [mobile phones rental, pocket Wi-Fi rental, SIM retailers and vending machines](https://www.narita-airport.jp/en/service/svc_19) in both terminal 1 and 2 at Narita Airport.