# Do you know a 100+GB SIM in Spain?

Tags: spain, cellphones, data-plans

I'm going to work remotely in Spain for one week and I wanted to know if there was a large (80-100 GB, ideally unlimited) data SIM plan with no engagement available in Spain?

My current SIM card give me 13 GB in EU. It will do the trick for a few days but not for something like 2 weeks.

I also plan on buying a Wifi modem that can take the SIM to use it as an access point. If you also have any suggestion I'm taking them. I plan on buying the TP-Link Routeur 4G 150Mb/s Seems like a good choice regarding its price.

Comment: What would be enough for you? 50 GB? 100 GB? It might be more useful to have a ballpark estimate rather than ask for an elusive unlimited plan.

Comment: Most mobile phone plans (even the non-prepaid ones) use a misleading definition of *unlimited*, they will advertise *unlimited* but in their conditions its unlimited for a *typical* usage and will throttle to unusable speeds afterwards which is a loophole in most countries. I'd say, don't expect more than 100-200GB of 4/5G speed in prepaid.

Comment: @Relaxed I would say that something around 80GB Would be Great. It's just that I saw in Portugal you have "unlimited" data SIM such as MEO for like 1€/day

Comment: @NicolasFormichella Well I think a100GB is enough afterward ^^'

Comment: Hi @Alexandre and welcome to Travel.SE. Thanks for clarifying what you're looking for. However, it's unclear what you've looked into so far. What do you find when you do a websearch for e.g. "100GB data sim spain". Do you find anything helpful? If not, why are the results not helpful for your case? Showing this kind of "research" prevents that others suggest things you've looked into already and allows others to suggest a helpful solution. Please [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102032/how-can-i-find-the-cheapest-prepaid-sim-card-for-a-given-country-or-multiple-cou

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I find the cheapest prepaid SIM card for a given country or multiple countries at a time?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/102032/how-can-i-find-the-cheapest-prepaid-sim-card-for-a-given-country-or-multiple-cou)

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking to go unlimited and you're going to use a wireless modem, you have a few options.

- [Orange](https://en.orange.es/) offers the Holiday Pass, which has unlimited data and a small allowance for making phone calls. The Holiday Pass 15, for example, is €25 for 15 days.
- [Vodafone](https://www.vodafone.es/c/particulares/es/productos-y-servicios/movil/prepago-y-recargas/tarifas-de-prepago/) (link in Spanish) offers a number of prepaid packages. The L, XL and XXL offers 100, 120 and 150 GB of mobile data respectively, and they cost €20, €30 and €40 for a month each.
- [Movistar](https://www.movistar.es/particulares/movil/tarifas-moviles/prepago-total) (link in Spanish) has the Prepago Total, which is €20 for four weeks. There's a promotion where the normal 35 GB data allowance is currently 140 GB.

Your data allowance also works in the rest of the EU, so if you decide to travel outside of Spain, you can use your allowance as you would normally. For Vodafone and Movistar, the allowance also covers travel to the UK, so you have options.